# Is human flesh halal for eating?

Tags: halal-haram, food, meat, human-body

Inspired by: [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19071/1713)

Of course, murdering someone is forbidden and mutilating a body is forbidden. But setting these issues aside, would human flesh be halal for eating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: In the name of Allah, Most Beneficent, Most Merciful]

If eating human flesh wasn't haraam, it would not have been compared to **backbiting.**

> #### [Al-Ĥujurāt :: Ayah 12](http://quran.com/49/12)
>
> O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. **Would one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead?** You would detest it. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance and Merciful.

When Backbiting is haraam, ....

> #### [Al-Humazah :: Ayah 1](http://quran.com/104/1)
>
> Woe to every slanderer and backbiter.

... so does eating human flesh.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Answer (score -2):

Eating Animals That eat other Animals is indeed Haram. But we are Humans, created from Earth. Not Animals, Created from Water. So that doesnt apply to Humans. What did the Prophet (saws) and the Sahaba say about this Topic? You did not put in any Daleel? Are you a heretic or just crazy?

Answer (score -4):

Consuming the flesh of animals that eat other animals is strictly forbidden. Since humans eat meat it would not be suitable for eating, as it is haram. However, if a human were to eat only vegetables, then they would be halal to eat because it would be the same as eating a sheep or a cow.

I hope you find this information useful and good luck with your pursuit of Islamic Enlightenment!

Comment: Is there a reference for this claim?  It sounds quite far fetched to me.